# Show that the groups $G$ and $\langle G, * \rangle$ are isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ be a group and $g\in G$. Define a new operation $*$ on $G$ by $a*b=agb$.

What I have done so far is up to showing that indeed $\langle G,*\rangle$ is a group. When showing that these groups are isomorphic I ended having trouble finding a function.

Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the map from the original $G$ into $(G,*)$ defined by $h\mapsto g^{-1}h$ and prove that it is a group isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be working on it.

Comment: This $g^{-1}$ here is the same as the identity element of $(G,*)$, right?

Comment: @Traveler Yes, it is. It had to be, because a group homomorphism always maps the identity element into the identity element. But you already knew that, right?! After all, you told us that you proved that $(G,*)$ is a group.

Comment: Got it. Very much appreciated.

Comment: May I just add on how can I find such mapping?

Comment: @Traveler Since $g^{-1}$ is the identity element of $(G,*)$, it would have to be a map the mapped $e$ into $g^{-1}$. This one seemed to be a natural choice for me.